# Odoo 13 import contacts csv method

Tags: python, xml, odoo, erp, odoo-13

I am using a sequence code number as a reference on my contacts(res.partner) and when I create the contacts it works perfectly, but when I import a contact list it doesn't create the sequence number.
I don't know what method odoo 13 uses to import data so I don't know what to change. Waht I need is that the sequence automatically creates on creation or import and doesn't have gaps or repeated numbers.

Here is my code:

model.py

```
class ResPartner(models.Model):
_inherit = 'res.partner'

ref = fields.Char(string='Reference', readonly=True)

@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    if 'ref' in vals and vals['ref'] == False:
        vals['ref'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('partner')

    return super(ResPartner, self).create(vals)
```

init.py

```
from . import models
from odoo import api, SUPERUSER_ID


def _auto_install_data(cr, registry):

env = api.Environment(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, {})

partner_ids = env['res.partner'].search([('ref', '=', False)])
for partner in partner_ids:
    partner.write({
        'ref': env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('partner')
    })
```

sequence.xml

```
<odoo noupdate="1">
    <record id="seq_res_partner" model="ir.sequence">
            <field name="name">Partner</field>
            <field name="code">partner</field>
            <field name="padding">8</field>
            <field name="number_next">1</field>
            <field name="number_increment">1</field>
            <field name="implementation">no_gap</field>
    </record>
```

views.xml

```
<record id="view_company_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">res.company.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" secuencia="base.view_partner_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//div[@class='o_row']" position="after">
            <group name="contact code">
                <field name="ref" string="Contact code"/>
            </group>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 1):

The import is not using `create()` IIRC, which should explain yor challenge here.

Instead Odoo is using `load()` (in `models.BaseModel`) which is returning a dictionary with IDs in it. So you could extend `load` to create sequences afterwards.

I would implement a method for the sequence part, and because it's already Odoo 13.0 you should use `api.model_create_multi` and a list of dictionaries as parameter.

```py
def _set_sequence(self):
    for partner in self.filtered(lambda p: not p.ref):
        partner.ref = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('partner')

@api.model_create_multi
def create(self, vals_list):
    records = super().create(vals_list)
    records._set_sequence()
    return records
```

As for the import part, you probably should extend `load()` which isn't that easy to give you code by now, because i don't have the data structures in mind. But the idea is to fill the `data` of `load()` with `ref` by using the sequence again. That can lead to lost numbers in cases of errors on import.

Comment: Actually I'm having lots of problems with this, when I install my module with the sequence, it automatically creates the reference sequence for all the contacts but if after that I create a new contact then nothing happens and if I import a list of contacts, also nothing happens. And last if I uninstall the module and install it again then the default contacts get a sequence and the imported ones gets other repeating the numbers. Example, the first regular contact gets 00000001 and the first imported contact gets 00000001 too. What can I do?

Comment: When removing or uninstalling the module nothing happens to the `ref` column of res.partner, because that is a base module column. The sequence if defined in your module will be deleted by Odoo, so next time installing (not updating!) it will be created again. If the sequence wasn't defined correctly - which means it's updateable - every update of your module will reset it. I don't know why updating or installing your module should set `ref` of your existing partners, because your code in the question just shows create() which won't be used on updating/installing of a module (except demo data)

Comment: It would be very helpful to see more of your code: XML with the sequence, other things were the sequence is used even it is not directly.

Comment: I edited my question and updated all my code

Comment: It's not working, when I install the module it does create the sequence and add it to res.partner but after that if I create a new contact or import a list nothing happens and the field just stay empty. Could I do it with a computed field?

Comment: The import can only work if you extend `load()`, but im wondering why the normal creation isn't working. I don't see mistakes either in my code not in yours.

Comment: Okay wait, my code should work but yours not in context of creation, because you check if `'ref'` is in `vals` which can't be for normal UI creation. You've set the field to readonly, so you won't see that field in `vals`. My code is working another way and should work.